# How to prevent wp_insert_post() to set Uncategorized category?

Tags: wordpress, post, insert

I'm  using `Wordpress 3.5` and it seems that `wp_insert_post()` cannot set categories anymore,  the documentation syas :

> post_category no longer exists, try wp_set_post_terms() for setting a
>   post's categories

The problem is that `wp_set_post_terms()` or `wp_set_object_terms()` require the `postID`, which is returned by `wp_insert_post()`. While this is fine to set category terms to the post inserted by `wp_insert_post()`, the problem is that every time I call `wp_insert_post()` I get the `Uncategorized` category in my post, in addition to the category terms I set after calling `wp_insert_post()`. How can I prevent the `Uncategorized` to be always there?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know where have you found that `wp_insert_post() can't set categories anymore` but from the [WordPress Doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) you can do it like

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => 'My post',
    'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_category' => array(8,39) // id's of categories
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Bellow is an working example of mine that I'm using in one my site to add new post dynamically by an admin with a category name of `location` with two meta fields, input taken from the user (I've filtered user inputs but omitted here)

```
$category='location'; // category name for the post
$cat_ID = get_cat_ID( $category ); // need the id of 'location' category
//If it doesn't exist create new 'location' category
if($cat_ID == 0) {
    $cat_name = array('cat_name' => $category);
    wp_insert_category($cat_name); // add new category
}
//Get ID of category again incase a new one has been created
$new_cat_ID = get_cat_ID($category);
$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => $_POST['location_name'],
    'post_content' => $_POST['location_content'],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_category' => array($new_cat_ID)
);
// Insert a new post
$newpost_id=wp_insert_post($my_post);
// if post has been inserted then add post meta 
if($newpost_id!=0)
{
    // I've checked whether the email and phone fields are empty or not
    // add  both meta
    add_post_meta($newpost_id, 'email', $_POST['email']);
    add_post_meta($newpost_id, 'phone', $_POST['phone']);
}
```

Also remember, every time you add a new post without a category, `WordPress` sets the default category for that post and it's `uncategorized` if you did not change it from the admin panel, you can change the default category from `uncategorized` to anything you want.

### Update:

Since the `post_category` is no more exists so you can replace

```
'post_category' => array($new_cat_ID)
```

with following

```
'tax_input' => array( 'category' => $new_cat_ID )
```

in the example given above. You can also use

```
$newpost_id=wp_insert_post($my_post);
wp_set_post_terms( $newpost_id, array($new_cat_ID), 'category' );
```

Remember that, in this example, the `$new_cat_ID` has been found using following line of code

```
$new_cat_ID = get_cat_ID($category);
```

but it's also possible to get the category id using following code

```
$category_name='location';
$term=get_term_by('name', $category_name, 'category');
$cat_ID = $term->term_id;
```

Read more about [get_term_by](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) function.

Comment: thanks! On the Wordpress DOC page you pointed, you can read " //post_category no longer exists, try wp_set_post_terms() for setting a post's categories" in the comments of the keys.